# Flutter not detecting vscode

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

I have my flutter in D drive and Vscode in C drive. So, when running `flutter doctor` on windows command prompt, it's showing that vscode is not installed. Is there a way to correct this problem without having to install vscode in D drive or changing the path of flutter to C drive. I installed it in D drive as my C drive is quite full.

Comment: That's [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) not [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) Both are different. And you don't necessarily need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have read it wrong, It should be asking about the Visual Studio not VS-Code. Both IDEs are different.

In flutter doctor, you are getting this error because whenever you need to develop Flutter app in VS-Code, you will still require some tools like SDK tools or some other dependencies. And VS-Code dosen't give you those dependencies out of the box. Therefore you will require either **Android Studio** or **Visual Studio**.

So If you have already installed either Visual Studio or Android Studio, then you can start developing a Flutter App without any worries or errors of those Flutter doctor command.